# Set Url For CSS and Javascript in ASP.NET / C# and Error when I deploy it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

Hai, I wanna ask something..
I was developed code in ASP.NET and C#. on masterpages i was added code similar for call javascript and CSS like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Css/reset.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

When I compiled it, it works 100 % but when I tried to deploy it to server..it doesn`t work. So if I want to running web on IIS I must change masterpage to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/reset.css" /> => remove /

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> => added ../
```

Can you give me a hint so I dont need to change code every time I want to deploy it to server..How I must write URL in masterpage?
FYI : My Structur Folder like this

-Solution

- CSS
- JS
- Masterpage
- Page Folder ASPX..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's a pain. I hope this post is what you are after.

[ASP.NET - path to use to reference .CSS and .JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735684/asp-net-path-to-use-to-reference-css-and-js)

Comment: I can`t write it in masterpage :(